# What is the purpose of declaring an undefined std::function before its definition?

Tags: c++, c++11

As [std::function in cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) referred, the implementation of `std::function` is to declare an undefined `std::function` before its definition. What is the purpose to declare this? Is it related to a template variadic class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This definition is for allow specialization of class. So, if you are trying to declare

```
std::function<ClassType> function;
```

You get compile-time error, that means, that `std::function` for this parameter is not defined, it's defined only for `std::function<ReturnType(Args)>`

Answer (score 1):

In the link referred,

```
template< class >
class function;
```

is the class template declaration. The second part

```
template< class R, class... Args >
class function<R(Args...)>
```

is a partial specialization, which cannot exist without the unrestricted declaration from the first part.